# Rotating the buttons in app when I rotate the iPad upside down

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, rotation, portrait

I'm programming an iPad application and I just wrote the rotate methods and there are some buttons. I used CGRectMake method and re-positioned buttons ... portrait and landscape modes all works fine but my problem is buttons are not re-positioned when I turn my ipad upside down. Need Help

Answer (score 1):

UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsidedown is the solution